# Why do I get the warning "This build used outdated Gradle functions, which makes it incompatible with Gradle 8.0".?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

When running with the **--warning-mode** all key, I get the following.

```
The JavaExec.main property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Please use the mainClass property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:main for more details.
```

But I don't use this parameter, I use **mainClass**.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.24.4'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

application {
    mainModule = 'pigletmodule'
    mainClass = 'piglet.Main'
}

javafx {
    version = "17.0.1"
    modules = ['javafx.controls']
}

jlink {
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'piglet'
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible one of the plugins is using the `JavaExec.main` property (my guess would be the JavaFX plugin).

Comment: If you can, run your build with `--scan` parameter. It will publish information about deprecations to the gradle scan server and you should be able to see more details helping you analyze it. See [this page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html) as an example how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As correctly guessed in the comments, the deprecation warning comes from the javafx issue. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin/issues/114) about this:

> In the current stable version, I get warning when I run this.
>
> ```
> .\gradlew run --stacktrace --warning-mode all
> ```
>
> The JavaExec.main property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Please use the mainClass property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:main for more details.
> It seems the problem of gradle-modules-plugin. Also, in the current version of this plugin, the problem already fixed.
>
> May I fix it and send PR?

Comment: According to https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin/issues/206, it was fixed in Gradle version 1.8.10.