# gradle cannot resolve dependecy project(":app") from other sub-project

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm new to gradle and still trying to understand it, so please assume I have no idea what I'm talking about if you give an answer. :) I'm using gradle 7.3.3.

I've got an Android app project that has the standard `app` module. In my `app` module is a class named `com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.DatabaseConfigUtil` and I want to be able to run `DatabaseConfigUtil.main()` and it needs to have all of the classes from `app` in the classpath.

I've created a second module named `libdbconfig` which is just a Java Library module so that I can create a JavaExec task which will call `DatabaseConfigUtil.main()` and make sure that all of the classes from `app` are in the classpath.

My `libdbconfig/build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":app")
}

task dbconfig(type: JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = "com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.DatabaseConfigUtil"
}
```

I sync AndroidStudio with my build.gradle changes and then try to run the `libdbconfig:dbconfig` task and get the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':libdbconfig:dbconfig'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':libdbconfig:runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :app.
```

I thought I understand how to declare a dependency on another sub-project and whenever I look at examples ([Example 11. Declaring project dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:dependency-types) it looks like I'm doing it right.

If I change my dependencies to remove the word "implementation" then the gradle config doesn't throw an error, but I don't understand that at all since it doesn't attach the dependency to a configuration (like "implementation").

```
dependencies {
    project(":app")
}
```

When I do that, the gradle task will start, but will ultimately fail because the classes from the `app` module are not in the classpath and so it can't find the class to run:

```
> Task :libdbconfig:dbconfig FAILED
Error: Could not find or load main class com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.DatabaseConfigUtil
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.DatabaseConfigUtil
```

Any help is appreciated. gradle has been voodoo to me for a long time and I'm trying to figure it out. I went through a udacity course on how to use it and I thought I had a much better understanding of it, but some of the basic things I thought I understood aren't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the way I was able to run my `main()` method with all of my Android project dependencies a different way, which I've described in detail in [Android Studio, generate Ormlite Configuration File (ormlite.txt), gradle complains "The JavaExec.main property has been deprecated."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694067/android-studio-generate-ormlite-configuration-file-ormlite-txt-gradle-compla)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, you need to include your subprojects in your **settings.gradle**, as follows:

```
include "app"
include "libdbconfig"
```

The example you referenced is for Gradle 7.4.2. Maybe take a look at [this example for 7.3.3](https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#multi_project_builds).

Comment: Yes, both of those subprojects are in the settings.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Module `:app` should configure itself; better use `buildSrc` or `includeBuild`. It's an anti-pattern to access anything else from a library module than another library. If you really have to configure the database in a strange way, apply a custom plugin to the `:app` module. And I just don't understand why this question is tagged as `android`, it reads `id 'java'` and not `id 'com.android.library'`?

For example, add `buildSrc/build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.gradle.java-gradle-plugin'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        DbConfigPlugin {
            id = 'com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.dbconfig'
            implementationClass = 'com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.DbConfigPlugin'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.2.1'

    testImplementation gradleTestKit()
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.2'
}

tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Then Gradle can execute Java code at build time:

```
class DbConfigPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(@NotNull Project project) {
        /* TODO: configure the database. */
    }
}
```

And it can be applied in module `:app` `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.inadaydevelopment.herdboss.dbconfig'
}
```

Else you'd have to stick to Groovy or Kotlin scripting.

Comment: It is tagged android because my primary project is an android app, as mentioned in the post. If this was just a java project, I wouldn't be having so much trouble trying to run my main method, which I need to do so that I can have the java code in my android project generate a config file that is needed by the java code in my android project. (ORMlite which generates a sqlite table config file)

Comment: The custom plugin option seems like an extreme solution, but I've been running out of other options, so I might have to go that route. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I don't understand where I'm supposed to put the code that you labeled as "buildSrc/build.gradle". Is that supposed to be a subproject sibling next to `:app`, and the project itself is just about defining this custom gradle plugin?

Comment: `buildSrc` is a default directory (it just maps as `:bin`). The mere question is if not a Groovy task - or Android resources could be used apply the configuration? `org.gradle.java-gradle-plugin` is the only option to run Java code there, but not the only option to configure a build.. It is entirely unclear what a `DatabaseConfigUtil` even is.

Comment: As I mentioned at the top of my post, I'm a -super- newbie with Gradle. I genuinely have no idea what you're trying to describe. I don't have a default `buildSrc` directory/module in my project. (I'm using Android Studio, not IntelliJ). And the question that starts with "The mere question..." I -genuinely- have no idea what that question meant.

Comment: Reading through this and trying to grok it... I don't know this will work for my scenario. My `app` project has some classes annotated with @DatabaseTable which is an ORMLite annotation. I need to run OrmLiteConfigUtil.writeConfigFile() which is part of the ormlite-android library. That code will look through all the classes in the classpath that have the @DatabaseTable annotation, inspect them, and generate a config file based on the info. If I try to reference that OrmLiteConfigUtil code outside of an android project, it fails because it relies on various android libs. (cont)

Comment: (cont) and if I have to define this custom plugin in a different subproject, then it doesn't have access to the classes in my `app` project, which are the ones that it needs to introspect in order to generate the config file. :/

Comment: I hope you will come back and try to help me understand this answer. I'm an old coder, but very very new to gradle.

Comment: One Android you can have one `res/raw/ormlite_config.txt` per source set; or migrate to [Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room); it generally seems a bit crappy: https://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite.html#Config-Optimization... it reads "You will need to run this utility locally on your development box (not in an Android device), whenever you make a change to one of your data classes."

Comment: You could as well make `:assemble` depend on `task dbconfig` ...but only in the `:app` module.

Comment: Room is awful if you're doing anything that is the tiniest bit complicated. Not an option. The ormlite_config.txt file is the thing I'm trying to generate. I know that I need to generate it whenever I change my db structure. That's the thing I'm trying to generate. But I can't run my main() method that calls OrmLiteConfigUtil.writeConfigFile() unless all of those classes are in the classpath. Depending on `:assemble` doesn't work because assemble smashes all the classes into .dex files and packages them in an apk. They aren't available in a format that I can use for the classpath.

Comment: That's the entire point.