# Use gradle to include classes from sub-project A in the classpath for sub-project B

Tags: java, gradle

I'm very new to gradle and was [having problems in a more complicated project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72724166/gradle-cannot-resolve-dependecy-projectapp-from-other-sub-project) which provides context to this overall question, so I decided to create a new, simple project to try to get the concept to work, but I still can't get it to work.

I have one sub-project called `core` and one sub-project called `db`. I have a class in the `db` project called `com.kenny.db.DBMain` which has a `main()` function that I want to run. `DBMain.main()` needs to use `com.kenny.core.*` classes that are defined in the `core` project.

I'm able to add a dependency in my `db/build.gradle` so that it depends on `:core`, but my code in `db` isn't able to see the classes from `core`.

db/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

dependencies {
    project(":core")
}
```

db/src/main/java/com/kenny/db/DBMain.java:

```
package com.kenny.main;

import com.kenny.core.*;

public class DBMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoreStuff stuff = new CoreStuff();
        System.out.println("db test, name="+stuff.name);
    }
}
```

When I try to build DBMain.java, it fails because it can't find `com.kenny.core.CoreStuff()` which was defined in the `core` project.

```
/Users/kenny/projects/gradlewtf/db/src/main/java/com/kenny/db/DBMain.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com.kenny.core;
                ^
  symbol:   class core
  location: package com.kenny
```

How do I get the classes from `core` available when compiling code in the `db` project?

--
Edit: Changed the `core` project code package to `com.kenny.core` and the `db` project code package to `com.kenny.db`. Still the same problem, the `db` project isn't getting the `core` code into the classpath so it cannot compile.

Comment: @Gardener The code in both projects are in the same Java package. If I explicitly write out the full package name for CoreStuff when declaring the stuff variable, I get exactly the same message. The problem isn't how I'm referencing the class, the problem is that the classes from the other package aren't available to my code in the db project.

Comment: So many questions...first, what version of Gradle is this?  What does your top-level `build.gradle` look like?  What about your `settings.gradle`?  What was the precise error you got from Gradle when attempting to build this?

Comment: @Makoto Gradle 7.3.3. There isn't a gradle error message, it's a javac compile error message which is explicitly included in the above post. The issue is that when trying to build the project, the java code in the `:db` project isn't able to access the classes from the `:core` project and so javac fails to compile the code in `:db` fails because it cannot find the referenced classes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I tried following the [documentation on the gradle website](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html) itself, but at every turn, their example code failed to even compile. That's because you need to already understand gradle in order to realize that you need to change their example code, but they don't really tell how/what you need to change. I mean, they try to tell you inside a paragraph later on, but unless you are already a gradle expert, those instructions don't make much sense.

I added this to my core/build.gradle file:

```
// this will create a configuration with the name "instrumentedJars" 
// that will include the implementation (i.e. my classes and 
// classes from dependencies)
configurations {
    instrumentedJars {
        canBeConsumed = true
        canBeResolved = false
        extendsFrom implementation, runtimeOnly
    }
}

// this will declare an "artifact" (i.e. a produced output) 
// for my :core project. It references the configuration name 
// "instrumentedJars" and says that it should include the 
// outputs of the task named "jar"
artifacts {
    instrumentedJars(jar)
}
```

Then in my project where I need to include those `core` classes, I added this to my db/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(path: ":core", configuration: 'instrumentedJars'))
}
```

Then I can build my `db` project and it is able to find the classes I need. Then when I need to run my main() method, I added a run task to my db/build.gradle:

```
task run(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn(":db:compileJava")

    mainClass = 'com.kenny.db.DBMain'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: This seems like a whole lot of work to do something which normally is accomplished with what you already had  in your question.

Comment: I've worked with Gradle for the last four years, and never in the history of ever during that time did I have to do this with the trivial use case of Project A depending on Project B.  My projects have several sub-projects in them as well.

Comment: Well, I've added an answer of my own.  Hopefully it points you in a better direction for the future.

Comment: @Makoto The larger context to this question is that I'm trying to get a java project to depend on an android project and the android project doesn't automatically define an output that the java project can easily depend on. If you can help me with this, it would be appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72724166/gradle-cannot-resolve-dependecy-projectapp-from-other-sub-project

Comment: You should've included that full context in your original question.  Mind adding it in?

Comment: I had mentioned the larger context, but I've linked to it in the first sentence.